# No funciona evaluación de usuario y contraseña

Tags: php, mysqli

Buenas tardes estoy intentando paso a paso que conecte mi proyecto a la base de datos, ya revise linea x linea y todo esta bien, intente con un proyecto diferente colocar mi Base de Datos, ingresa una vez y a la segunda sale error o sino sale un aviso que dise **(el usuario no esta registrado en la base de datos nueva**), sale otro error. elimine la tabla y la cree nuevamente teniendo en cuenta el md5 y nada, los códigos están correctamente enlazados pero sigue sin aparecerme la información

***Este es el archivo principal index1***

```
   

     <?php
        extract ($_REQUEST);
        if (!isset($_REQUEST['x']))
            $x=0;
        ?>
        <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html>
        <head>
            <meta charset="UTF-8">
          <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, shrink-to-fit=no">
          <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
          
        <title>MedSyS</title>   
        </head>
        <body>
             <?php include "Vista/iniciarSesion.php" ?> 
        </body>
        </html>
        
        ***Este es el código que maneja la base de datos index2***
        
        <?php
        session_start();
        extract ($_REQUEST);
        if (!isset($_SESSION['user']))
            header("location:../index1.php?x=2");//x=2 significa que no han iniciado sesión
        if (!isset($_REQUEST['pag']))
            $pag='contenido';
        
        if (!isset($_REQUEST['msj']))
            $msj=0;
        ?>
        <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html lang="es">
        
          <head>
            <meta charset="utf-8">
            <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
            <title>Centro Médico</title>
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css"> <!--Iconos-->
            <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:100,300,400,500" rel="stylesheet">
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/font-awesome.min.css">
        
        </head>
        <body>
        
        
            <div id="divEncabezado"><?php include "encabezado.php";?></div>
            <div id="divMenu"> <?php include "menu.php";?> </div>
            <div id="divContenido"> <?php include $pag.".php" ;?> </div>
            <div id="divPiePagina"><?php include "piePagina.php";?> </div>
        
        </body>
        </html>
        
        ***Este archivo es validar inicio de sesión***
        
        <?php
        session_start();
        extract ($_POST);
        require "../Modelo/conexionbasesdatos.php";
        /* los variables que viene del formulario son: $login, $password */
        /*asigno a la variable password el valor encriptado de lo que colocaron
        en el password del formulario, ya que así esta en la base de datos */
        $login = $_POST['documento'];
        $pass = md5($_POST['password']);
        
        $objConexion=Conectarse();
        // Vamos a realizar el proceso para consultar los pacientes
        //Guardamos en una variable la sentencia sql
        $sql="select * from usuarios where usuLogin = '$login' and usuPassword = '$pass'";
        //Asignar a una variable el resultado de la consulta
        $resultado=$objConexion->query($sql);
        //verifico si existe el usuario
        $existe = $resultado->num_rows;
        
        if ($existe==1)  //quiere decir que los datos estan bien
        {
            $usuario=$resultado->fetch_object() or die ("Error");
            $_SESSION['user']= $usuario->usuLogin;
            header("location:../Vista/index2.php?pag=contenido");
        }
        else`introducir el código aquí`
        {
            header("location:../Vista/index2.php?pag=iniciarSesion&x=2");  //x=2, quiere decir que el usuario no esta registrado
        }
        ?>
```

Comment: Estás creado el hash de la contraseña de nuevo y sobre esa comparar lo cual no es correcto, para este caso debes usar password_verify

Comment: es decir reemplazo password_verify en todas o solo en el archivo validar sesión de inicio para que me aparezca la base de datos?

Comment: Espera estoy formulando una respuesta

Answer (score 0):

Tomando como punto de partida la respuesta de [DanMossa](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27482611) para proponer una solución:

Considera establecer los siguientes aspectos:

- Mediante una estructura de tipo *try/catch* evaluaremos si la consulta se ejecuta
- En caso de que no sea así entonces atrapamos la excepción e imprimimos el mensaje de error

  - Para este punto usaremos lo siguiente:

    - El uso del método [`mysqli_report`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.mysqli-report.php)
    - Y como parámetro le pasamos a ese método la bandera [`MYSQLI_REPORT_ALL`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli-driver.report-mode.php#refsect1-mysqli-driver.report-mode-parameters)

Lo anterior no esta considerado en la **respuesta de referencia** pero siempre es bueno y altamente útil considerarlo ya que si la consulta tiene algún problema para ejecutarse es bueno que el sistema sea capaz de avisarnos al respecto.

- Dado que tienes el hash de tu contraseña en la base de datos, entonces:

  - No debes crear un nuevo hash de la misma al momento de que la recibes
  - Debes usar el método [`password_verify`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.password-verify.php) el cual devolverá un booleano en función de que el hash solicitado sea idéntico al de la contraseña ingresada
- Siempre que la consulta se constituya de valores dinámicos, será *mas seguro* construirla mediante [sentencias preparadas](https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli.prepare.php)
- Una vez que indicamos las columnas deseadas en función del filtro por medio de la evaluación de igualdad del nombre de usuario (*asumo que login es eso*) vinculamos los resultados por medio del método [`bind_result`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli-stmt.bind-result.php) a sus correspondientes variables
- Usamos el [método `fetch`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli-stmt.fetch.php)
- En este tipo de consultas yo considero útil indicar [el uso de `LIMIT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/limit-optimization.html)
- Ahora mediante un condicional compruebo 2 condiciones (*a diferencia de la respuesta de referencia*):

  - Si la variable donde se almacena el nombre del usuario es distinto de `NULL` y
  - El método `password_verify` retorna true por la igualdad de los 2 valores a comparar

    - Una vez que estos 2 puntos anteriores se cumplan asignamos a la clave `user` en las variables del array `$_SESSION` el nombre del usuario recuperado

      ```
        session_start();
        extract ($_POST); //Esto no lo comprendo yo hasta pensaría en quitarlo

        mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ALL);

        require "../Modelo/conexionbasesdatos.php";

        $login  = $_POST['documento'];
        $pass   = $_POST['password'];

        $objConexion=Conectarse();

        try {
            $sql = $objConexion->prepare("
                                            SELECT usuLogin, usuPassword 
                                            FROM usuarios 
                                            WHERE usuLogin = ?
                                            LIMIT 1
                                        ");
            $sql->bind_param('s', $login);
            $sql->execute();
            $sql->bind_result($usuarioLogin, $passwordLogin);
            $sql->fetch();

            if ($usuarioLogin != NULL && password_verify($pass, $passwordLogin)) {
                $_SESSION["user"] = $usuarioLogin;
                header("location:../Vista/index2.php?pag=contenido");
            } else {
                header("location:../Vista/index2.php?pag=iniciarSesion&x=2"); 
            }
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            echo $e->getMessage();
        }
      ```

Considera que la lógica que expones pudiera resultar mas útil para evaluar por ejemplo si un registro existe o no, pero que no te ocupa recuperar los valores de determinadas columnas.